# MonoDevelop - Open Visual Studio .Net project/solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, mono, monodevelop

I have the following .Net project (solution, *.sln) that opens perfectly in Visual Studio 2010, but I can not open it in MonoDevelop.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "TCDF.Sinj.Padrao", "TCDF.Sinj.Padrao\", "{3E21A4FF-66FE-4BEC-A7C2-82E09B44913F}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/TCDF.Sinj.Padrao"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "TCDF.Sinj.Padrao\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\TCDF.Sinj.Padrao\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/TCDF.Sinj.Padrao"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "TCDF.Sinj.Padrao\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\TCDF.Sinj.Padrao\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "10502"
        VWDDynamicPort = "false"
        VWDVirtualPath = "/sinjpadrao"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {3E21A4FF-66FE-4BEC-A7C2-82E09B44913F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {3E21A4FF-66FE-4BEC-A7C2-82E09B44913F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

The following error is displayed:

> Error while trying to load the project
>   '/home/eduardo/Data/Temp/20180906.1/sinj/Sistemas/TCDF_APL_WEB_SINJ/TCDF.Sinj.Padrao/':
>   File not found:
>   /home/eduardo/Data/Temp/20180906.1/sinj/Sistemas/TCDF_APL_WEB_SINJ/TCDF.Sinj.Padrao/

[image]

**QUESTION:** Why is this error happening? Any solution?

NOTE I: I can open other projects created in Visual Studio 2010 perfectly in MonoDevelop.
NOTE II: Apparently the problem occurs because of the absence of a "* .csproj" file.
NOTE III: The project does not have any C# code, just web content files (css, htm, js, etc).

**FURTHER QUESTION:** If this is some limitation of MonoDevelop, then how do we get around it?

NOTE: I just want that MonoDevelop create an "ASP.NET Development Server" just like Visual Studio 2010 does.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this thread is related to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065820/file-open-website-in-monodevelop

Comment: `E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A` is a "Web Site" project and not supported by MD, try "Visual Studio Code" as that runs on Linux.

Comment: what version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Site project type was something very Windows centric and bind strictly to IIS and Windows. Leave it as it is and merely use VS on Windows please. Don't bother yourself in this way, as Mono/MonoDevelop is not designed to be fully compatible to everything.

Comment: @knocte Version 7.6! Thanks

Comment: Is it fixed? Otherwise you can post the project file, not the ".sln" one, which contains all paths and dependencies.